# Apache rewrite url segment and query param

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Hi I'm trying to convert a URL like this;

```
http://www.test.com/segment/aaa?uid=1
```

To this;

```
http://www.test.com/segment/new/aaa/u/1
```

This is the closest I can come up with but the first match is segment/aaa instead of just aaa. I can't find a way to isolate just the aaa portion so I can change it to segment/new/aaa instead of segment/aaa.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/segment/(.*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([up])id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ segment/new/$1/%1/%2? [L]
```

The URL that this yields is:

```
https://www.test.com/segment/new/segment/aaa/u/3
```

Thanks!

Comment: the submask `$1` contains `segment/`. try this regex `^segment/([^/]*)$`

Comment: That produces the same output as what I have above. Why does that match contain the entire string instead of just the regex portion like the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([up])id=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^segment/(.*) segment/new/$1/%1/%2? [L]
```